# Preloader disappears when sidebar is loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux, jsx

For example: i have 2 controll-view container user.cv.jsx and sidebar.cv.jsx

Screen consist of User and Sidebar. Sidebar rendering in User screen.

User container:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import UserTypeComponents from '../components/user_type.jsx'
import Sidebar from '../../sidebar/containers/sidebar.cv.js'

import * as showList from '../action/list.action.js';
import * as userLimit from '../action/limit.action.js';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {...state}
}

class UserType extends React.Component {

    constructor (props, context) {
        super(props);
        this.context = context;

        if(!this.props.oauth.isAuthenticating) {
            this.context.router.history.push('/login');
            return;
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (<div>
                    <Sidebar />
                    <UserTypeComponents {...this.props} />
               </div>);
    }

}

UserType.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserType);
```

And Sidebar Container:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import ShowSidebar from '../components/sidebar.jsx';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import Preloader from '../../../helpers/preloader.helper.js'

import * as active from '../action/active.action.js'
import * as list from '../action/list.action.js'
import * as show from '../action/show.action.js'

import {DEFAULT_COMPONENTS} from '../constant/sidebar.const.js';


function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return state.sidebar
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {

  return bindActionCreators({
        ...active,
        ...list,
        ...show
    }, dispatch);
}

class Sidebar extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
  }

  listOfLinks(){
    const makeRequest = async () => {
        try {
          const data = await (await fetch('http://localhost:3000/sidebar')).json(),
                active = this.activeComponent(data);

          this.props.list(data);
          this.props.active(active);

        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
      }

      makeRequest()
  }

  activeComponent(data){

    for(let key of data){

      if(location.pathname.indexOf(key.name.toLowerCase()) != -1){
        return key.name.toLowerCase();
      }
    }

    return DEFAULT_COMPONENTS;

  }

  componentWillMount() {

      this.listOfLinks();

  }

  activeSidebarState(event){

      let parent = event.target.parentNode,
          target = _$('.site-sidebar__name', parent),
          text = target.innerText.toLowerCase();

      this.props.active(text);
  }

    render() {

    const loading = this.props.sidebar.links.length;

    return (loading ? <ShowSidebar changeActive={::this.activeSidebarState} active={this.props.sidebar.active} links={this.props.sidebar.links} /> : <Preloader />);

    }

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Sidebar);
```

For all this, action and redusers are written. The sidebar sends a request to the server and requests all the modules and forms links to them, too. The user module is accessing the server and requires all users. The problem is that the preloader is being formed in the sidebar, and when the sidebar is loaded the preloader disappears. But the users still could not boot.
The question is: How to control the loading of the sidebar and the user, so that when these two components are updated, the state remove the preloader.

Comment: It is not recommended to make async calls at `componentWillMount`, rather use `componentDidMount`

Comment: it's just an example. The question is different.

Answer (score 0):

A common practice is to store `isFetching` flag in the reducer and update it in respond to fetch actions. For example:

```
function users(state = { users: [], isFetching: false }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_USERS_START':
      return { ...state, isFetching: true };
    case 'FETCH_USER_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, isFetching: false, users: action.payload.users };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Then you can access it from both your components via `mapStateToProps` and show the preloader.

A main thing here is that you need to move the async call to an action, so reducer will be able to react to it. You can use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware.

Comment: Yes, but my preloader to be in sidebar. Maybe I'm calling wrong preloader

Comment: `code`
render() {

    const loading = this.props.sidebar.links.length;

    return (loading ? <ShowSidebar changeActive={::this.activeSidebarState} active={this.props.sidebar.active} links={this.props.sidebar.links} /> : <Preloader />);

    }
`code`

Comment: You will be able to access `isFetching` flag from the sidebar component and show the preloader.

Comment: that is now I need to check when rendering:

`code`
(!this.props.sidebar.isFetching && !this.props.user.isFetching) ? <User /> : <Preloader />